# How to write custom files in Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a problem with writing custom output of a pig job

I basically want to write the stats of the execution time of pig job , into a file
My pig job is ready and is working.

How can I now write the stats of the execution time
format : start time, end time, (end-start time) execution time

Kindly guide me as to should I try to do this with pig or write a shell script , call java code methods to do somthing for me..
Thanks in advance..
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Start time, end time and elapsed time for the job will be present in the logs when you execute the MR job. I don't think a way to do this using PIG. But if you know about hadoop counters, you can create your own custom counters based on your requirements and pragmatically write the output to the file you have created.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Pig version 0.14` then the time taken by pig script will be dumped in the last line of `console log`, something like this

```
 "Pig script completed in 48 seconds and 454 milliseconds (48454 ms)"
```

But the same time completion logs will not be available in `<=0.13 releases`

One option could be, you can call your pig script inside the shell script and calculate the time execution. This approach will not give  100% exact result but it will be very close to the original execution time.

**myshell.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
START_TIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))

pig -x local mypigscript.pig

END_TIME=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
TOTALMILLSECS=$((($END_TIME-$START_TIME)-1200))
SECS=$((TOTALMILLSECS/1000))
MILLSECS=$((TOTALMILLSECS%1000))

cat > MYOUTPUT.txt <<EOF
STARTTIME:$START_TIME, ENDTIME:$END_TIME, TIMETAKEN:$SECS seconds and $MILLSECS millseconds ($TOTALMILLSECS ms)
EOF
```

To cross verify the shell script result, I just took the below pig script and executed in both 0.14 and also in the above shell script. I didn't see much difference in the execution time.

**input**

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,8
```

**mypigscript.pig**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2,f3);
B = GROUP A BY f1;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, COUNT(A);
DUMP C;
```

**Execution time of the above pigscript in 0.14:**

```
org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 48 seconds and 460 milliseconds (48460 ms)
```

**Execution time of the above pigscript using shellscript:(output will be stored in MYOUTPUT.txt)**

```
STARTTIME:1427606934083, ENDTIME:1427606983729, TIMETAKEN:48 seconds and 446 millseconds (48446 ms)
```

**Note:**
I just provided an approach to get the execution time, you can customize or modify according to your need.